# What Hermeneutical attributes are most important (For new Bible Tool)?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

I'm a software engineer and I've built a bible analytics tool specifically to analyze various doctrines across denominations, ranking applicable verse higher based largely on the hermeneutics.

I'm doing a revamp of the voting tool, before i would simply have a +3 to -3 on if a verse is for or against a doctrine, a single point for:

1. If it's in context
2. If it's the plain sense (it is not metaphoric or symbolized in it's interpretation)
3. If it's a teaching passage vs. some historical narrative.

So my question is this.  What attributes should i be tracking with verse submissions to aid in calculating how applicable a certain verse should be considered?

Along with the attributes, if you wish to weight in, what weight should they be given (ex: taking the plain sense of a verse is more important than if it's a teaching vs. historical passage).

Thanks everyone!

if you do want to check out the tool (although login is disabled during this week for an upgrade), it's Bibleanalytics.org

Comment: General questions like this, without reference to a particular verse or passage, however brilliant they are, are usually considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: I agree.  Unfortunately, this is not the place for such a question.

Comment: Sorry, do you know where a good place to ask this?  The people here are concerned with proper exegetical handling of scripture so i was hoping to gain some input from like-minded christians.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not the place for such questions I will provide a few hints that may be helpful.  In my judgement, Bible hermeneutics can boiled down to the following:

- Syntax (matters of grammar)
- Semantics (meanings of words)
- Context (what is the broader topic being discussed)
- Cross references (what else has the author or other said about this same matter)
- Culture and idiom (what meanings these expressions have in the culture of the author)

Now to my personal bias.  As a Christian, I also ask myself what a Bible passage is telling me about God's and Jesus' nature and dealings.  Further, I would regard all these as (almost equally) important and must be considered together to understand a Bible passage.

Comment: This is the most important, but difficult to measure, even personally:"If anyone’s will is to do God’s will, he will know whether the teaching is from God or whether I am speaking on my own authority."  (John 7:17, ESV)  The principles you mention can help judge this.  The question is how willing are people to let the Scriptures correct them.  "All Scripture is breathed out by God and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness, that the man of God may be complete, equipped for every good work."  (2 Tim. 3:16–17, ESV)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to join the software discussion over at B-Greek:

http://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=47

Comment: Thanks, i'll inquire there as well!